# Why do I see response instead of my document?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I'm trying to understand Service Workers, so I started from simple example

```html
<!-- index.html -->

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport"
              content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <script defer type="module" src="index.js"></script>
        <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            Hello, my dear!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
// index.js

const registerServiceWorker = async () => {
    const registration = await navigator.serviceWorker.register('service-worker.js', {
        scope: './'
    });
};

await registerServiceWorker();

const response = await fetch('https://v1.cdqnpk.net/videvo_files/audio/premium/audio0137/watermarked/MusicComedyThe CTE02_96.3_preview.mp3');

console.log(response);
```

```js
// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
    event.preventDefault();

    event.respondWith(new Response(JSON.stringify({text: 'test test test'}), {
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }))
})
```

But I can't get data in `console` like usual `JSON` responses instead of it `JSON` rendering instead of whole my document

P.S. The link in `fetch` is broken to get error. The [original link](https://v1.cdnpk.net/videvo_files/audio/premium/audio0137/watermarked/MusicComedyThe%20CTE02_96.3_preview.mp3) (it is mp3 file if you follow the link the file will start download)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, if I understand it correctly, the fetch event listeners replaces global fetch handler, which is used also for getting the html page. In sample you provided you add respondWith to response with `{text: 'test test test'}` with no regard to where the request comes from.

You can see the difference if you would check for the request url in your service worked event listener, for example:

```js
// service-worker.js

self.addEventListener("fetch", (event) => {

  if (
    event.request.url ===
    "https://v1.cdqnpk.net/videvo_files/audio/premium/audio0137/watermarked/MusicComedyThe CTE02_96.3_preview.mp3"
  )
    event.respondWith(
      new Response(JSON.stringify({ text: "test test test" }), {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
      })
    );
});
```

Read more on [Custom responses to requests (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers#custom_responses_to_requests):

> 1. A fetch event fires every time any resource controlled by a service worker is fetched, which includes the documents inside the specified scope, and any resources referenced in those documents (for example if index.html makes a cross-origin request to embed an image, that still goes through its service worker.)

Comment: Oh, thank you very much! I didn't notice that he catch any `fetch` not only my `fetch`es